# How to create a file/folder from jar in Java?

Tags: java, jar

I have converted my JavaFX project into a jar file and these posts helped me to successfully read media files from my local environment that are needed in my project:

- [Media folder in jar file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8681981/media-folder-in-jar-file)
- [How to read a file from jar in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3369794/how-to-read-a-file-from-jar-in-java)
- [Including pictures and sound files in a runnable jar file from Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27348016/including-pictures-and-sound-files-in-a-runnable-jar-file-from-eclipse)

Now at one part of the project I need to create a folder in my pc during the project runtime, that will store some data gained through the program. Now I am using this command to execute that purpose:

```
String file_name= String.valueOf(Main.class.getResource("data stored/"+name+"-"+Long.toString(time)));
    new File((file_name)).mkdirs();
```

Here I just followed the similar steps that I used for reading the file ( Which is mentioned in the attached posts). But when I run the jar file, everything works fine except that, the folder is not created. And if I don't write this part: `Main.class.getResource`, the jar file shows an error which is obvious. I think the reason might be, for reading, it needs the reference of the main class, but for creating a folder, referring with respect to a class is not correct.

My path of main class:
`src/brainwave/Main.java`

Path of the folder I want  to create:
`src/data stored`

Any suggestion please how can I solve this issue?
Thanks.

Comment: please keep your tags focused - this is plain java, unrelated to javafx. And stick to java naming conventions when showing code publicly

Comment: you cannot modify the jar file while the application is running. If you want to do that, you will have to do some creative copying of the jar, adding a folder, and repackaging, and then run the new version...

Comment: a `.jar ` is only a way of packaging your java aplpication for distribution - essentially it's a `.zip` file with some information about the java application stored inside...

Comment: How do you get the path where the file should be saved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getResource` will retrieve a path into the JAR file, in case the class file is also coming from there; otherwise a *normal* path, if not running from JAR.

Use a plain `File` to get a path to a file/directory (e.g. `new File("data/files/")`) that is not saved in the JAR